# I am trying to convert and upload Raw image to server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to upload image to my server with php. i have two files one is index.php and upload php file is myscript.php

Index.php

```
<div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

<h1>Mugshot Test Page</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

<div id="my_camera"></div>

<!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.min.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<!-- A button for taking snaps -->
<form>
    <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }//UP TILL THIS POINT CODE IS WORKING FINE. 
        Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'myscript.php',function(code, text){
        //will add success code later
        });
</script>
```

myscript.php

```
<?
$name = date('YmdHis');

$imagename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."images/".$name.".jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], $imagename);
?>
```

this code meant to do 3 things

1. On click capture image
2. Show me how i look in captured image
3. Upload image to the server

Up till 2 step its working fine on third it doesnt do anything.  may be something wrong with my php. i dont know please help

Comment: What is the output? Is it showing any errors?

Comment: nope. meant to show me image in the "images" directory but nothing is there i have check the write permissions too ... but dunno whats wrong with it.

Comment: Can you see the network tab? Is there any api call in the tab?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying upload data that is not available. When you are taking snapshot the snap method is providing with data_uri. Once that data is received store that in a global variable. Then later try to upload that data on a separate event (Maybe on a button click).

```
    var data = null;
    function take_snapshot() {
     // take snapshot and get image data
     Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) { 
      data = data_uri;
     // display results in page
     //.... Write rest of the codes here to display
    })


 // Call this function from an event, probably  on a button click to upload data
     function upload_data() {
        // Use the stored variable here to upload
       Webcam.upload( data,
        'myscript.php',function(code, text){ //will add success code later 
        });
       }
```